# Calling a hadoop job from java code without a jar

Tags: java, hadoop, jobs

I used this code to run the word count hadoop job. WordCountDriver runs when I run it from inside eclipse with the hadoop eclipse plugin. WordCountDriver also runs from the command line when I package the mapper and reducer classes as a jar and drop it in the classpath.

However, it fails if I try to run it from the command line without adding the mapper and reducer class as a jar to the classpath although I added both the classes to the classpath. I wanted to know is there some restriction in hadoop from accepting mapper & reducer classes as normal class files. Is creating a jar always mandatory ?

`public class WordCountDriver extends Configured implements Tool {`

```
public static final String HADOOP_ROOT_DIR = "hdfs://universe:54310/app/hadoop/tmp";


static class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private Text word = new Text();
    private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line.toLowerCase());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
};

static class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;

        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get(); // process value
        }       
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
};


/**
 * 
 */
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = getConf();

    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "universe:54311");

    Job job = new Job(conf, "Word Count");

    // specify output types
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // specify input and output dirs
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(HADOOP_ROOT_DIR + "/input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(HADOOP_ROOT_DIR + "/output"));

    // specify a mapper
    job.setMapperClass(WordCountDriver.WordCountMapper.class);

    // specify a reducer
    job.setReducerClass(WordCountDriver.WordCountReducer.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(WordCountDriver.WordCountReducer.class);

    job.setJarByClass(WordCountDriver.WordCountMapper.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCountDriver(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear which classpath you're referring to, but in the end, if you're running on a *remote* Hadoop cluster, you need to provide all classes in a JAR file that is sent to Hadoop during the `hadoop jar` execution. The classpath of your local program is irrelevant.

It is probably working locally since you are actually running a Hadoop instance inside the local process there. So, in that case it happens to be able to find the classes in your local program's classpath.

Comment: My driver class is local and hadoop is setup as a 1-node cluster

Answer (score 1):

Adding classes to the hadoop classpath will make them available client side (i.e. to your Driver).

Your mapper and reducer need to be available cluster-wide, and to make this easier on hadoop, you bundle them up into a jar and either supply with the Job.setJarByClass(..) class, or add them to the job classpath using the -libjars option with the GenericOptionsParser:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html